# SELECT Rows Older Than Date Only If Row Does Not Have Row Newer Than Date

Tags: mysql

I have the below table where I would like to 'prune' out nicks who have not gained points in 1 week. I'm new to MySQL and I'm not sure how to best SELECT these rows. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have so far that is not yielding correct results. The results this yields are nicks who have earned points at any time it seems.

```
SELECT * FROM points_log p1
    INNER JOIN points_log p2 ON p1.nick = p2.nick
    AND p1.dt < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
WHERE p2.dt > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK LIMIT 10;
```

Here is the table:

```
mysql> describe points_log;
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| nick              | char(25)              | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| amount            | decimal(10,4)         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| stream_online     | tinyint(1)            | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| modification_type | tinyint(3) unsigned   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| dt                | datetime              | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I'll take it back to the drawing board if I have a few moments later this evening.  Clearly I've missed a syntax error somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `nick`s who have scored in the past week using an aggregation:

```
SELECT pl.nick
FROM points_log pl
GROUP BY pl.nick
HAVING MAX(pl.dt) < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK;
```

I'm not sure what you want as final output, but this will return the `nick`s that have scored in the past week.

Comment: This worked as expected however I was looking for nick's that **haven't** scored in the last week so I changed the operator to: `< NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK` and it worked to find rows matching my original question. If you could edit your response I will accept this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @PrestonConnors . . . I interpreted "I would like to 'prune' out nicks who have not gained points in 1 week" as saying that you want to keep the ones who have gained paints in the past week.

Comment: I couldn't figure out the best way to word my question, it is a little confusing if you haven't been working with this database and overall project for a while.